# curl -c command powershell - cookie file location

Tags: rest, powershell, curl

I'm using powershell curl commands to make REST API Calls. When I run the curl command with -c option,

`curl https://sampleurl/api/sessions -i -X POST -H X-Api-Version:x.x -c mycookie -d email=$email -d password=$passwd`

Where is the "mycookie" file stored in this case. For security purposes, I need to make sure it is safeguarded.

The documentation doesn't give much information here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl's `-c` option saves (all known) cookies into the given file name. The file name is in your current directory, or if you use a path too, relative to the current directory.

You can of course also specify a full absolute path name to specify exactly where you want that cookie file to be saved.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks. Yes , I see it there. Could you also let me know if there is a workaround to not create the file in the physical realm in the interest of security? Maybe like a temp file?

Comment: I don't understand how what curl does would be different if it would save to a "temp file" ? You may consider it a temp file and remove it when you're done using it. You can often make your command lines work with cookies without saving them at all.

Comment: Could you provide the link or point to some documentation where I can use command line to work with the cookies without having to save them?

Comment: That's a different question and its hopeless to have a discussion in SO comments, but a very basic command line: `curl -b  - example.com/1 example.com/2 example.com/3`